# swiper vertical slider should work when I reached on top

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

```js
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            effect: "creative",
            direction: 'vertical',
            parallax: true,
      speed: 700,
      mousewheel: {
        releaseOnEdges: true,
                forceToAxis: true,
      },    
            slidesPerView: 1,
      freeMode: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      creativeEffect: {
        prev: {
          translate: [0, 0, -1],
        },
        next: {
          translate: [0, "100%", 0],
        },
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      }
    });
```

```css
        .swiper-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .swiper-slide:nth-child(even) {
            background: aliceblue;
        }
    
    .swiper-slide:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #ffffff;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <hr>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <hr>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The issue is with a vertical swiper slider on a web page. Currently, the slider only starts working when the user scrolls down, and the user wants it to start functioning immediately when they reach the top of the page, creating a seamless experience. The user is seeking a solution to modify the code to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Can you put more code? i want see html structure :), and swiper version(cdn is better)